# 400 Bad request on a POST service

Tags: java

I'm attempting to build a POST method for a Java web service utilising Jersey RS that consumes JSON, however I am receiving a 400 bad request error when I submit some sample JSON.

```
@Path("/Register")
@Stateless
public class RegistrationController {

    @POST
    @Path("/Test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String postHelloWorld(String message){
        return "temp";
    }
```

Above is the code for the post method, and when I attempt to use an API service such as Postman to submit a post request to

http://localhost:37846/Register/Test

Using Postman to set a header of Content-Type as application\json, with some sample JSON such as

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

I receive the 400 bad request error.

---

Response body:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1 - Error report</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        <!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request</h1>
    <hr/>
    <p><b>type</b> Status report</p>
    <p><b>message</b>Bad Request</p>
    <p><b>description</b>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.</p>
    <hr/>
    <h3>GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1 </h3>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Attempting to print the message using System.out failed, as did a generic system.out.print("hello") message, which leads me to believe that the method is not being called.
Since I'm not receiving a 404 error, and when I tweak the data types I'll receive a 415 Unsupported Media type error, this rules out something such as incorrect mapping.
JSON is not malformed, so problem likely lies with either the submitted request or how the web service handles the request.

Comment: Debug the program! Print the incomming `message`. Does the request work for methods without consuming JSON?

Comment: 400 Bad Request means the /test endpoint is expecting different parameters than you're sending. Are you using a JSON object mapper such as Jackson? If so, you'll need to create an object containing the same values as menu in your JSON (Id, value, popup)

Comment: 400 means that you are sending bad data most of the time. Are you sure there is no response body with error description? A good service should have it.

Comment: Agreed with @JakeMiller but try this adding "@RequestBody" in front of String message. You might get all that post body as string, if that's what you really want. Otherwise do as Jake suggested.

Comment: @ppasler This may be a silly question, but I'm unsure of how to print out on a webservice similar to System.out.println() in a standard application. It's running on a Glassfish server currently.

Comment: @Andrew you can still use System.out.println

Comment: @Andrew could you also provide the `Request` that is sent?

Comment: @ppasler Edited OP to include. It says that the request syntax is wrong, however I'm unsure how since the JSON isn't malformed and the method/request header are both set to JSON.

Comment: what web/app server are you using and what REST provider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was a typo in the header.

```
Content-Type application\json
```

Was what was causing the 400 error.
The header that resolves the problem is

```
Content-Type application/json
```